# How to convert data from Array of Objects efficiently

Tags: javascript, data-conversion

I am getting an array of objects like this from my API

```
[
    {
        [...]
        time: "2022-01-27T18:21Z",
        attributes: {
            [...]
            temp1: 12,
            temp2: 49,
            [...],
            tempN: 23
            [...]
        },
        [...]
    },
    {
        [...]
        time: "2022-01-27T18:26Z",
        attributes: {
            [...]
            temp1: 13,
            temp2: 49,
            [...],
            tempN: 22
            [...]
        },
        [...]
    },
    [...]
]
```

And I need to convert these to an object like this:

```
{
    temp1: [
        ["2022-01-27T18:21Z", 12], ["2022-01-27T18:26Z", 13], [...]
    ],
    temp2: [
        ["2022-01-27T18:21Z", 49], ["2022-01-27T18:26Z", 49], [...]
    ],
    [...]
    tempN: [
        ["2022-01-27T18:21Z", 23], ["2022-01-27T18:26Z", 22], [...]
    ]
}
```

I don't know how or even if any `temp` values are present in the original dataset. And it is possible that one object in the API data has for example `temp5`, but the next does not. The dataset has at least a couple hundred to a few thousand objects.

What is an efficient way to convert the dataset?

Comment: Are the temp-names always in ascending order? So if `temp5` exists, then `temp1` through `temp4` will also exist?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) what you have there is just an object.. Please don't abuse names to the point of meaninglessness.

Comment: You have to post a real json, if you need the real help

Comment: It's not really an object... more of an object literal. From now on, I suggest we call these things what they are: "Data that was received in serialized form as JSON, currently represented as an object in-memory in a computing system, serialized again as an object literal and pasted here".  It rolls right off the tongue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I'd do it like a groupBy on temps...

```js
const data = [{
    time: "2022-01-27T18:21Z",
    attributes: {
      temp1: 12,
      temp2: 49,
      tempN: 23
    },
  },
  {
    time: "2022-01-27T18:26Z",
    attributes: {
      temp1: 13,
      temp2: 49,
      tempN: 22
    },
  },
]

const byTemps = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  let temps = Object.keys(el.attributes).filter(key => key.startsWith('temp'));
  temps.forEach(temp => {
    if (!acc[temp]) acc[temp] = [];
    acc[temp].push([el.time, el.attributes[temp]]);
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(byTemps)
```